# MongoDb c# driver 2.0 BsonNull usage

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I have `isDeleted` `Nullable` property in `Profile` class.

```
Builders<Profile>.Filter.Eq(p => p.IsDeleted, BsonNull.Value)
```

But the following code raised next compilation error:

```
Error 11    Cannot convert lambda expression to type 
'MongoDB.Driver.FieldDefinition<MongoDB.DataTypes.Profile,MongoDB.Bson.BsonNull>' 
because it is not a delegate type
```

How to implement a null-check ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `IsDeleted` is nullable, you can just use a simple `null` instead of `BsonNull.Value` when you query:

```
Builders<Profile>.Filter.Eq(p => p.IsDeleted, null)
```

Comment: How about if you want to use a different data type, like int ?

Comment: @AdrianFaciu If you want the query to by typed the value needs to be the same type as the property. So there's only a single data type possible, `bool?`.

Comment: Yes, I actually meant a different data type for the property. If the property is int.

Comment: @AdrianFaciu If it's a reference type, you can use `null`. If it's a value type, you need to make it a nullable one and use `null`.

Comment: Can you provide a reference on this by any chance?

Comment: @WesternAussie on what?